# to read the single line echoed text from php web server using android

Tags: php, android

i just want to read the single line text that is echoed from the php web server .
but the my code reads the echoedd text along with the web pages source code i just want to remove the source code and get only the text is there any way to get text separately

```
           httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost= new HttpPost("http://www.rock.bugs3.com/check.php");             
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(newBasicNameValuePair("username",
            et.getText().toString().trim())); 
            $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];
            nameValuePairs.add(newBasicNameValuePair("password",
            pass.getText().toString().trim())); 
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
            System.out.println("Response : " + response); 
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);
            dialog.dismiss();
```

i am new to both android as well as php .this is my php code which i have used

```
<?php
$hostname_localhost ="mysql.serversfree.com";
$database_localhost ="u154090_donor";
$username_localhost ="u154090_donor";
$password_localhost ="abcd";
$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$query_search = "select * from tbl_user where username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password. "'";
$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query_exec);
//echo $rows;
 if($rows == 0) { 
 echo "No Such User Found"; 
 }
 else  {
    echo "User Found"; 
}
mysql_close($localhost);
?>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should choose a better transport protocol between your client and server.
HTML is meant to be rendered by a browser, and implies how the data is visually represented.
If you have programmed an endpoint in your PHP server that you call the get some data (only raw data without visual representation) your PHP script should output the data you need encoded in XML or JSON.

If you PHP definitively outputs HTML, [you should use a XML parser](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) in your android application to get the data you need inside the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The data sent back is controled by your php script check.php, not be the client.  If there's too much data being sent back, the bug is in your php script or in your web server configuration.

Comment: i am just new to both fields android and php can you check the above php – @GaRRaPeTa